# What is considered to be an anti-pattern when updating state using createSlice from Redux-Toolkit?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following `createSlice` code where there is the reducer `setCustomEquipment` that modifies the state. Is the `=` approach a valid way to mutate the state when using `createSlice`, or should I use the shallow state copy approach anyway regardless of whether I am using `createSlice` or not?

```js
export const someSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'some',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setCustomEquipment: (state, action: PayloadAction<CustomEquipment[]>) => {
      // Variant A 
      state.customEquipment = action.payload;

      // Variant B
      // return {
      // ...state, { state.customEquipment : action.payload }
      // }
    },
```

Comment: Title is overly broad and does not match question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either method you are using is fine, and entirely your decision.

Mutable update

```js
setCustomEquipment: (state, action: PayloadAction<CustomEquipment[]>) => {
  state.customEquipment = action.payload;
}
```

Return shallow copy into new reference

```js
setCustomEquipment: (state, action: PayloadAction<CustomEquipment[]>) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    customEquipment: action.payload,
  };
}
```

When using Redux-Toolkit slice reducers the allowed methods of updating state are to write mutable state update ***or*** to return a new state reference, e.g. a shallow copy of the previous state with overwritten properties.

See [Direct State Mutation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#direct-state-mutation) for details.

> To make things easier, `createReducer` uses [immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) to let you
> write reducers as if they were mutating the state directly. In
> reality, the reducer receives a proxy state that translates all
> mutations into equivalent copy operations.

> Writing "mutating" reducers simplifies the code. It's shorter, there's
> less indirection, and it eliminates common mistakes made while
> spreading nested state. However, the use of Immer does add some
> "magic", and Immer has its own nuances in behavior. You should read
> through [pitfalls mentioned in the immer docs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/pitfalls). Most importantly,
> **you need to ensure that you either mutate the `state` argument or return a new state, *but not both***.

From the pitfalls:

> ### Don't reassign the recipe argument
>
> Never reassign the draft argument (example: `draft = myCoolNewState`).
> Instead, either modify the draft or return a new state.

So basically the anti-patterns are:

- Mutating draft state object ***and*** returning a new state reference

  ```js
  setCustomEquipment: (state, action) => {
    state.otherPropery = "foo";

    return {
      ...state,
      property: action.payload,
    };
  }
  ```
- Reassignment of the current state draft object

  ```js
  setCustomEquipment: (state, action) => {
    state = {
      ...state,
      otherPropery: "foo",
      property: action.payload,
    };
  }
  ```

Comment: This answers really clear things up.